# I'm trying to install the NVIDIA version of a toolkit, and I'm getting error messages like "... this declaration may not have extern "C" linkage"

Tags: nvcc

I'm trying to install the NVIDIA version of an externally supplied toolkit (for the purposes of this message it doesn't matter what the toolkit is, this is a problem about how to use nvcc), and I'm getting error messages like "usr/include/c++/6/utility(329): error: this declaration may not have extern "C" linkage".

I'm not a C or C++ programmer, but I am happy enough poking around in things like Makefiles. I'm pretty sure that I've got all the paths set to point to the right places, and /usr/include/c++/6 contains all the files that are generating the error messages. But I have no idea what these error messages mean and what I should do to get round them.

Comment: Why would you need HTK, there are many more modern and accurate toolkits. They are easy to use too.

Comment: That really isn't a helpful answer. I am aware of the existence of other toolkits, notably kaldi, and I have sound reasons for wanting to use the HTK for my particular task. I love stack overflow, but I do find that too often you get told off for asking a question rather than being given an answer.

Comment: This is not an answer, just a comment

Answer (score 0):

I believe these errors are from C/C++ name mangling differences and the fact that NVCC compiles as a C++ compiler. I was able to compile HTK 3.5 by simply removing the `extern "C"` declarations from `HCUDA.cu`:

```c
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

/* ... */

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

I suspect that, because they're already declared `extern "C"` in `HCUDA.h`, they don't need to be declared such in `HCUDA.cu`, but I'm not sure.